# Best way to store many small files from memory to cloud storage

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-storage

I wish to store a lot of images from memory on the cloud. I'm looking for the best cloud storage option for these images where I would have a minimum of http calls to make.

I currently use google cloud storage but batch upload from memory is not possible. To use google cloud storage I have to use either their client librairies and make one HTTP request per item I want to upload (very slow) or write all my files on disk (also very slow) to upload in batch.

What would be my best option?

Answer (score -1):

DATA TRANSFER SERVICES, could be the best choice,whether you have access to a T1 line or a 10 Gbps network connection, Google offers solutions to meet your unique data transfer needs and get your data on the cloud quickly and securely.

Fast offline, online, or cloud-to-cloud data transfer.